# Eigen Error: static assertion failed C++ after replacing fftw_malloc array with eigen

Tags: c++, c++11, eigen, fftw

I am trying to switch my code and start using Eigen library in C++ since I have heard it is really good with matrices. Now my old C++ code used mostly fftw_malloc to initialize my arrays like the following:

```
static const int nx = 10;
static const int ny = 10; 

double *XX;
XX = (double*) fftw_malloc(nx*ny*sizeof(double));
memset(XX, 42, nx*ny* sizeof(double)); 

for(int i = 0; i< nx; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j< ny+1; j++){
        XX[j + ny*i] = (i)*2*M_PI/nx;
    }       
}
```

So I changed it to the following,

```
Matrix <double, nx, ny> eXX;
eXX.setZero();

for(int i = 0; i< nx; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j< ny+1; j++){
        eXX[j + ny*i] = (i)*2*EIGEN_PI/nx;
    }       
}
```

This however returns the error:

```
In file included from /mnt/c/Users/J/Documents/eigen-3.4.0/eigen-3.4.0/Eigen/Core:164,
                 from /mnt/c/Users/J/Documents/eigen-3.4.0/eigen-3.4.0/Eigen/Dense:1,
                 from Test.cpp:21:
/mnt/c/Users/J/Documents/eigen-3.4.0/eigen-3.4.0/Eigen/src/Core/DenseCoeffsBase.h: In instantiation of ‘Eigen::DenseCoeffsBase<Derived, 1>::Scalar& Eigen::DenseCoeffsBase<Derived, 1>::operator[](Eigen::Index) [with Derived = Eigen::Matrix<double, 10, 10>; Eigen::DenseCoeffsBase<Derived, 1>::Scalar = double; Eigen::Index = long int]’:
Test.cpp:134:16:   required from here
/mnt/c/Users/J/Documents/eigen-3.4.0/eigen-3.4.0/Eigen/src/Core/DenseCoeffsBase.h:408:36: error: static assertion failed: THE_BRACKET_OPERATOR_IS_ONLY_FOR_VECTORS__USE_THE_PARENTHESIS_OPERATOR_INSTEAD
  408 |       EIGEN_STATIC_ASSERT(Derived::IsVectorAtCompileTime,
      |                                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/mnt/c/Users/J/Documents/eigen-3.4.0/eigen-3.4.0/Eigen/src/Core/util/StaticAssert.h:33:54: note: in definition of macro ‘EIGEN_STATIC_ASSERT’
   33 |     #define EIGEN_STATIC_ASSERT(X,MSG) static_assert(X,#MSG);
      |                                                      ^
```

I see the error is pointing at line: `eXX[j + ny*i] = (i)*2*EIGEN_PI/nx;`
I am fairly new to Eigen and still trying to understand my way around so any feedback/suggestions would help. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The assertion message `THE_BRACKET_OPERATOR_IS_ONLY_FOR_VECTORS__USE_THE_PARENTHESIS_OPERATOR_INSTEAD` already tells you what the error is: Do not use `operator[]` but instead use [`operator()`](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1DenseCoeffsBase_3_01Derived_00_01WriteAccessors_01_4.html#ae6ba07bad9e3026afe54806fdefe32bb), like so:

```
#include <Eigen/Core>

int main()
{
  static const int nx = 10;
  static const int ny = 100;

  Eigen::Matrix<double, nx, ny> eXX;
  eXX.setZero();

  for (int i = 0; i < nx; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < ny; j++) {
      eXX(i, j) = i * 2 * EIGEN_PI / nx;
    }
  }
}
```

Also note that your code has undefined behavior because the `j` loop goes to `<= ny` due to the `+1` in the loop condition, meaning that the last iterations cause out-of-bound accesses to the array. Indeed, Eigen issues an assertion (in debug).

Moreover, since Eigen matrices are [column major](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TopicStorageOrders.html) by default, it is more efficient to exchange the row and column loops (but of course this only matters for larger matrices):

```
#include <Eigen/Core>

int main()
{
  static const int nx = 10;
  static const int ny = 100;

  Eigen::Matrix<double, nx, ny> eXX;
  eXX.setZero();

  for (int j = 0; j < ny; j++) {
    for (int i = 0; i < nx; i++) {
      eXX(i, j) = i * 2 * EIGEN_PI / nx;
    }
  }
}
```

Since the elements of each row have the same value here, we can also use [`row()`](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialBlockOperations.html) together with `setConstant()` to simplify the code:

```
#include <Eigen/Core>

int main()
{
  static const int nx = 10;
  static const int ny = 100;

  Eigen::Matrix<double, nx, ny> eXX;
  for (int i = 0; i < nx; i++) {
    eXX.row(i).setConstant(i * 2 * EIGEN_PI / nx);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is VERY helpful. The thing I am implementing here is a bit tricky since it's a mixed numerical method so sizes are not necessarily nx*ny but nx by ny+1. I did fix the outer band issue as well and had no idea that Eigen matrices are column major by default. Again very helpful since I am planning to parallelize this code.

Comment: Your welcome. In general, I'd advise to use as much of Eigen's existing functionality as possible. E.g. instead of writing loops yourself, try to find a corresponding Eigen construct, as for the `row()` example. That way you have a higher chance of getting faster code because Eigen can vectorize more. Regarding parallelization, Eigen can [automatically parallelize a few select operations](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicMultiThreading.html). Regarding storage order, you can switch to [row major](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TopicStorageOrders.html) if necessary.

Comment: wow, thanks again! Will be checking the parallelization link as well.